# How do I disable listing of directories in Apache?

Tags: linux, apache

Does Apache have an option to disable directory listing globally? (But it will still allow me to use index.php as my main page)

Note: I have many virtual hosts and subdomains and what not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible. You should use the **Options** directive with the -Indexes param

For example, in Centos /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf update **Directory /** to:

```
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

This way all child configuration will enhirit this restriction.

Note that each child can override this if the directive **AllowOverride** is set to **Indexes** or All (This effect override params in .htaccess files)

Comment: But there is dozens of directories, virtual hosts, and alias. Where does <Directory /> point?

Comment: I added the original comments. As you can see the / set this as the default directive. Search your httpd.conf file. the default directive is there.

Comment: But we don't use the default directory in production. There are 3 virtual domains and like 30 subdomains. And 2 alias. I don't want to add -Indexes for all these 35 different paths. I want to disable it globally.

Comment: The default directive behavior is inherited by all virtual host. So if you configure it to deny listening then all virtual hosts will inherit this (unless overridden locally)

Comment: Newer versions of Apache require a prefix for all options:   Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes    (I know the question is old, but I found myself here while searching for the syntax)